# How to run tests based on test tag of testng.xml using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

As I know, we can run tests via maven like:

## For classes:

```
mvn clean -Dtest=Class1,Class2 test
```

## For groups:

```
mvn clean -Dgroup=groupName test
```

But, I want to run tests based on `<test>` tag mentioned in testng.xml via mvn command. I mean what command I need to run for running `Sanity` and `Regression` tests. Please refer to following testng.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Sanity" >
    <packages>
       <package name="org.test.c" />
    </packages>
  </test>

  <test name="Regression">
    <packages>
      <package name="org.test.a"/>
      <package name="org.test.b"/>
    </packages>
  </test>
</suite>
```

## Note:

I've added testng.xml details under `suiteXmlFiles` tag of pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a complete list of options avaialble for the maven test goal use the command:

```
mvn surefire:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=test
```

You can specify a test by file name

```
mvn test -Dtest=MyTest
```

and by group name

```
mvn test -Dgroups=groupName
```

You can specify the list of suite xml files to use

```
mvn test -DsuiteXmlFiles=testng.xml
```

The help on this option specifies

> This parameter is ignored if the test parameter is specified (allowing you
>         to run a single test instead of an entire suite).

Looking at the list of options and considering this last remark we can conclude that the feature you requiring (selecting a test defined in the testng.xml file frome the command line) is not implemented in maven 3.0.4.